# Выводится в таблице только одно значение Json, как исправить?

Tags: php, json, api

Результат этого кода - первые данные в таблице, последующие за таблицей.

```
<style>  


        .table {
                width: 100%;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
            table {
                max-width: 100%;
                background-color: transparent;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-spacing: 0;
            }
            tbody {
                display: table-row-group;
                vertical-align: middle;
                border-color: inherit;
            }
            tr {
                display: table-row;
                vertical-align: inherit;
                border-color: inherit;
            }
            .table th, .table td {
                padding: 8px;
                line-height: 20px;
                text-align: left;
                vertical-align: top;
                border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
            }

            user agent stylesheet
            td, th {
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: inherit;
            }
            td{width:150px;}

    </style>
```

Где-то ошибка в коде, а вот где.

```
 <table class="table"><tbody><tr><td>Рейсы</td><td>Отправление</td><td>Прибытие</td><td>Дни курсирования</td></tr><tr>
    <?php 
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v1.0/schedule/?apikey=*******&format=json&uid=038AA_tis&station=s9623404&lang=ru&thread=false");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $json=json_decode($response,true);

    ?>




    <?php 
    foreach ($json['schedule'] as $schedule): 
    ?>

    <td><?= $schedule['thread']['short_title']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $schedule['departure_time']; ?></td><td> <?= $schedule['arrival_time'] ? $schedule['arrival_time'] : 'Не указано'; ?></td> 
    <td> <?= $schedule['days']; ?></td></tr>
    </tbody></table>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Не получается, все также

Comment: Так вы определитесь, у вас PHP неверно документ формирует? Тогда выкинуть из вопроса CSS и добавить, что именно сейчас формирует PHP в результате и что в этом неверно. Или у вас проблема с CSS? Тогда выкинуть нафиг PHP и заменить статичной табличкой на пару строк. И переписать теги вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
  $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v1.0/schedule/?apikey=51c9c870-925a-4058-9f23-613e5b74c93b&format=json&uid=038AA_tis&station=s9623404&lang=ru&thread=false");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $json = json_decode($response,true);
?>

<table class="table"><tbody><tr><td>Рейсы</td><td>Отправление</td><td>Прибытие</td><td>Дни курсирования</td></tr>
<?php foreach ($json['schedule'] as $schedule): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?= $schedule['thread']['short_title']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $schedule['departure_time']; ?></td><td> <?= $schedule['arrival_time'] ? $schedule['arrival_time'] : 'Не указано'; ?></td> 
    <td><?= $schedule['days']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Не смешивайте отображение и вычисления. Запутаетесь же в элементарных вещах.

Answer (score 2):

Перенесите открывающий таг `<tr>` внутрь цикла.

А закрывающие `</tbody></table>` - наружу.

Comment: Не получается, все так же

Answer (score 0):

Потому что, у тебя каждую итерацию закрывается таблица`</tbody></table>`; только разметка *конца* строчки `</tr>`  вносится каждую итерацию.
И переоткрыватать теги, только что бы не писать `echo` - серьёзно? Эти острова реально более читаемы, нежели нижеприведенный формат? С подсветкой переменных, и прочее:

```
$out .= "<tr>
             <td>{$somevar[someprop]}</td>
             <td>{$somevar[nextprop]}</td>
             <td>{$somevar[finally]}</td>
         </tr>";
```

И кроме того:

```
?>Какова задача этого пробела?




<?php
```